# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory on jenkins

Tags: mysql, jenkins, sonarqube5.1

I am using Sonarqube with MySql. I have Jenkins in place and I would like to integrate Sonar runner with TC for differents projects mainly (Java, PHP). I have done following :

1. Download sonar zip (last version) in windows plateform.
2. StartSonar.bat
3. I have a MySQL in CentOS in Remote VM :

   - I connect to remote MySQL using Cygwin ssh:
   - then I create a schema, as follow :

MySQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE sonar CHARACTER SET UTF8;
CREATE USER 'sonar'@'*' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';
GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'*';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

4. Then I disabled the VM firewall with : `sudo systemctl stop firewalld`
5. When I start my sonar with `StartSonar.bat`, I have the following error:

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'sonar'@'10.1.162.61' (using password: YES))
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:115) ~[sonar-core-5.1.2.jar:na]
    ... 28 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'sonar'@'10.1.162.61' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
```

What am I missing here, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to enable sonar credentials in sonar.properties in conf folder as follow :

```
# User credentials.
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar

#----- MySQL 5.x
# Only InnoDB storage engine is supported (not myISAM).
# Only the bundled driver is supported.
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://10.1.163.103:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
```